# exuberant ctags exclude non out-of-line constructor C++

Tags: c++, exuberant-ctags

When I'm trying to navigate to the definition of a class, it's very handy to have a unique ctags entry. Constructors share the name of the class and result in the creation of additional ctags entries that make navigation more difficult. For instance, in Vim, `g<c-]>` will navigate to a ctag without prompting if there's a single entry, but will force the user to manually disambiguate in other cases.

I don't want to miss out-of-line constructors that might be hiding somewhere, but I am okay with missing constructors in the body of the main class (even if the body itself is quite large).

Here's a class template in the file `foo.cpp`.

```
template <typename T> class LinkedList {
public:
  T head;
  LinkedList<T> *tail;

  LinkedList(T item) : head(head), tail(nullptr) {}
};
```

And here's `ctags -f- foo.cpp` (for exuberant ctags 5.8).

```
LinkedList  foo.cpp /^  LinkedList(T item) : head(head), tail(nullptr) {}$/;"   f   class:LinkedList
LinkedList  foo.cpp /^template <typename T> class LinkedList {$/;"  c   file:
head    foo.cpp /^  T head;$/;" m   class:LinkedList    file:
tail    foo.cpp /^  LinkedList<T> *tail;$/;"    m   class:LinkedList    file:
```

The entry `LinkedList   foo.cpp /^  LinkedList(T item) ... f    class:LinkedList` is not that interesting.

It would be fairly straightforward to write a script to parse the output of ctags and exclude things that look like non out-of-line constructors or to apply some kind of heuristic... I'm wondering if there's a more general/traditional/accepted solution for decluttering ctags output.